# How to search for a user by name using Spotify Web API

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to create an Android application that contains a feature where you can search for Spotify users by name. When using Spotify, you can search for a user by their ID or by their name. However, currently, I see no way that the Spotify Web API supports searching users by name. If you have the User ID, you can access their profile using the Web API. But I was hoping there was a way that you could run a search for the User name and get their ID that way.

Spotify's Web API allows you to search for a "track" or "artist", where they will return all of the search results. So why can't you do the same with User names? Is there any way to make this work that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an interesting question, since it regards user data of a huge community, so I will try to figure out.

First, you can clearly see that the Spotify Web API endpoint [`search`](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/)
has a `type` parameter that admits only the following types: `artist`, `playlist`, and `track`. 
Let's try it out to run from here (note: see the `Promise.all` solution to fetch data I'm using [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464464/promise-how-to-implement-in-this-situation/36464638#36464638))

**NOTE**
Recent Spotify `search` APIs will require an access token to be specified in the request headers:

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"
```

```js
var spotifyAccessToken = "YourSpotifyAccessToken";
var console = {
    log: function(s) {
      document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += s + "<br/>"
    }
  }
  // Simple XMLHttpRequest
  // based on https://davidwalsh.name/xmlhttprequest
SimpleRequest = {
    call: function(what, response) {
      var request;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
          request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e) {
          try {
            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
          } catch (e) {}
        }
      }
      // state changes
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) { // done
          if (request.status === 200) { // complete 
            response(request.responseText)
          } else response();
        }
      }
      request.open('GET', what, true);
      request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + spotifyAccessToken);
      request.send(null);
    }
  }
  //PromiseAll
var promiseAll = function(items, block, done, fail) {
  var self = this;
  var promises = [],
    index = 0;
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    promises.push(function(item, i) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (block) {
          block.apply(this, [item, index, resolve, reject]);
        }
      });
    }(item, ++index))
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(function AcceptHandler(results) {
    if (done) done(results);
  }, function ErrorHandler(error) {
    if (fail) fail(error);
  });
}; //promiseAll

// LP: deferred execution block
var ExecutionBlock = function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
  var url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/"
  url+=item;
  SimpleRequest.call(url, function(result) {
    if (result) {
      console.log( JSON.stringify( result, null, 2)
                  .replace(/\\n/g,"<br>").replace(/\\"/g,'"'));
      resolve(result);
    } else {
      reject(new Error("call error"));
    }
  })
}

arr = [
  "search?type=playlist&q=%22doom%20metal%22",
  "search?type=playlist&q=Adele"]
promiseAll(arr, function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
  console.log("Making request [" + index + "]")
  ExecutionBlock(item, index, resolve, reject);
}, function(results) { // aggregated results
  console.log("All response received " + results.length);
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
}, function(error) { // error
  console.log(error);
});
```

```html
<div id="console" />
```

All those objects are self defined, but one: `playlist`. 
In fact we can see from this response that we have `user` objects like (example):

```
"owner" {
    "external_urls": {
   "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/12345678"
 }
```

Nice!, the `external_urls` are user profiles url, while the `href` are playlists url (that require authentication btw) so that we can first grab them from this `json` response:

```js
var console = {
        log: function(s) {
          document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += s + "<br/>"
        }
      }
      // Simple XMLHttpRequest
      // based on https://davidwalsh.name/xmlhttprequest
    SimpleRequest = {
        call: function(what, response) {
          var request;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
            try {
              request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch (e) {
              try {
                request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
              } catch (e) {}
            }
          }
          // state changes
          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) { // done
              if (request.status === 200) { // complete 
                response(request.responseText)
              } else response();
            }
          }
          request.open('GET', what, true);
          request.send(null);
        }
      }
      //PromiseAll
    var promiseAll = function(items, block, done, fail) {
      var self = this;
      var promises = [],
        index = 0;
      items.forEach(function(item) {
        promises.push(function(item, i) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if (block) {
              block.apply(this, [item, index, resolve, reject]);
            }
          });
        }(item, ++index))
      });
      Promise.all(promises).then(function AcceptHandler(results) {
        if (done) done(results);
      }, function ErrorHandler(error) {
        if (fail) fail(error);
      });
    }; //promiseAll

    // LP: deferred execution block
    var ExecutionBlock = function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
      var url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/"
      url+=item;
      SimpleRequest.call(url, function(result) {
        if (result) {
          
          JSON.parse(result).playlists.items.map(function(item,index) {
            var userProfileUrl = item.owner.href;
            console.log( JSON.stringify( userProfileUrl, null, 2)
                      .replace(/\\n/g,"<br>").replace(/\\"/g,'"') ); 
          })
          
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          reject(new Error("call error"));
        }
      })
    }

    arr = [
      "search?type=playlist&q=%22doom%20metal%22",
      "search?type=playlist&q=Adele"]
    promiseAll(arr, function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
      console.log("Making request [" + index + "]")
      ExecutionBlock(item, index, resolve, reject);
    }, function(results) { // aggregated results
      console.log("All response received " + results.length);
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    }, function(error) { // error
      console.log(error);
    });
```

```html
<div id="console" />
```

At this point you will see a list of spotify `user` objects urls like (example url)

```
"https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/12345678"
```

So now we can fetch user profiles url (no auth required):

```js
var console = {
    log: function(s) {
      document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += s + "<br/>"
    }
  }
  // Simple XMLHttpRequest
  // based on https://davidwalsh.name/xmlhttprequest
SimpleRequest = {
    call: function(what, response) {
      var request;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
          request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e) {
          try {
            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
          } catch (e) {}
        }
      }
      // state changes
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) { // done
          if (request.status === 200) { // complete 
            response(request.responseText)
          } else response();
        }
      }
      request.open('GET', what, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
  }
  //PromiseAll
var promiseAll = function(items, block, done, fail) {
  var self = this;
  var promises = [],
    index = 0;
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    promises.push(function(item, i) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (block) {
          block.apply(this, [item, index, resolve, reject]);
        }
      });
    }(item, ++index))
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(function AcceptHandler(results) {
    if (done) done(results);
  }, function ErrorHandler(error) {
    if (fail) fail(error);
  });
}; //promiseAll

// LP: deferred execution block
var ExecutionBlock = function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
  var url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/"
  url += item;
  SimpleRequest.call(url, function(result) {
    if (result) {

      var profileUrls = JSON.parse(result).playlists.items.map(function(item, index) {
        return item.owner.href;
      })
      resolve(profileUrls);
    } else {
      reject(new Error("call error"));
    }
  })
}

arr = [
  "search?type=playlist&q=%22doom%20metal%22",
  "search?type=playlist&q=Adele"
]
promiseAll(arr, function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Making request [" + index + "]")
    ExecutionBlock(item, index, resolve, reject);
  }, function(results) { // aggregated results

    console.log("All profiles received " + results.length);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0], null, 2));

    ///// promiseall again

    var ExecutionProfileBlock = function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
      SimpleRequest.call(item, function(result) {
        if (result) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(result);
          resolve({
            name: obj.display_name ,
            followers: obj.followers.total,
            url : obj.href
          });
        }//result
      })
    }//ExecutionProfileBlock

promiseAll(results[0], function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
              //console.log("Making request [" + index + "] " + item)
              ExecutionProfileBlock(item, index, resolve, reject);
            }, function(results) { // aggregated results
               console.log("All response received " + results.length);
              console.log( JSON.stringify(results, null, 2) );
            }

            ,function(error) { // error
              console.log(error);
            })



    /////


  },
  function(error) { // error
    console.log(error);
  });
```

```html
<div id="console" />
```

Get it out! At this point we can see `user` objects with `display_name` and `followers` count like (example json):

```
{
    "name": "Joe Deere",
    "followers": 666,
    "url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/12345678"
}
```

So, to recap, the starting point is `playlist` search type in the search api. Given that, you can get user profiles with no authentication. Assumed that you obtain valid oauth tokens you can fetch top charts to do further queries.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your first section of code. It looks like you are making a playlist search with the keywords "doom metal" and "Adele". From what I understand, you found users based on those playlist results. Are these users that are affiliated with playlists containing Adele or doom metal? Does this mean that to find a user profile I need to know information about their playlists? I fail to see how this code uses input info "user name" at all, all I see is playlist info being the input.

Comment: @OMGitzMidgar Yes this is the only way to have users as output, since there is no way to query for usernames, if you in the answer the only objects you can query are artist, album, track and playlist. But, given playlists, you can have usera as output, that is half of the issue ;)